# Dividing by zero error in Python?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm writing a program where the user enters a, b, c, d, e, and f and displays the result. If ad - bc = 0, I'm supposed to report that there is no solution. But even when I include the part of code where:

```
if denominator == 0: print("The equation has no solution")
```

I keep getting a dividing by zero error. The numbers I use for the prompt are 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0 respectively. Here's my code:

```
def cramersRule():

a = float(input("Enter a: "))
b = float(input("Enter b: "))
c = float(input("Enter c: "))
d = float(input("Enter d: "))
e = float(input("Enter e: "))
f = float(input("Enter f: "))

denominator = ((a * d) - (b * c))

x = (((e * d) - (b * f)) / denominator)
y = (((a * f) - (e * c)) / denominator)
e = ((a * x) + (b * y)) 
f = ((c * x) + (d * y))
if denominator == 0:
    print("The equation has no solution.")
else:
    print("x is", x , "and y is" , y)
```

Please help!

Comment: you must set denominator to be a float.

Comment: Check if it's zero before you try to do calculations with it, not after.

Comment: Imagine you were offered a drink, and there was a small chance it could be poison.  You would check it was poison *before* you drank it, not drink it *then* check if it is poison.  In this analogy, poison==zero in the denominator, and drinking==division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing calculations with it:

```
x = (((e * d) - (b * f)) / denominator)
y = (((a * f) - (e * c)) / denominator)
```

That's why you get the error. You must first check if the denominator is zero.

```
def cramersRule():

    a = float(input("Enter a: "))
    b = float(input("Enter b: "))
    c = float(input("Enter c: "))
    d = float(input("Enter d: "))
    e = float(input("Enter e: "))
    f = float(input("Enter f: "))

    denominator = ((a * d) - (b * c))

    if denominator == 0:
        print("The equation has no solution.")
    else:
        x = (((e * d) - (b * f)) / denominator)
        y = (((a * f) - (e * c)) / denominator)
        e = ((a * x) + (b * y)) 
        f = ((c * x) + (d * y))
        print("x is", x , "and y is" , y)
```

Comment: So how would I get around it? Don't assign it as a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Everyone else has solved the problem you asked about; here's the problem you didn't ask about, better code organization!

```
from __future__ import division       # all division is floating-point
import sys

# version compatibility
if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    inp = raw_input                   # Python 2.x
else:
    inp = input                       # Python 3.x

def get_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(inp(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def cramers_rule(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    denominator = a*d - b*c
    if denominator:
        x = (e*d - b*f) / denominator
        y = (a*f - e*c) / denominator
        e = a*x + b*y
        f = c*x + d*y
        return x, y, e, f
    else:
        return None  # no solution

def main():
    prompt = "Enter {0}: ".format
    kwargs = {ch:get_float(prompt(ch)) for ch in 'abcdef'}
    res    = cramers_rule(**kwargs)

    if res is None:
        print("The equation has no solution.")
    else:
        print("x is {0} and y is {1}".format(*res))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

.

1. Each function should only do one thing: `cramers_rule()` should calculate Cramer's Rule, it should not be doing input and output. Having `cramers_rule()` accept arguments and return the result means it can be reused (ie in actual calculations).
2. Error checking on inputs - it's nice if it doesn't crash if, when you ask the user for a float, they enter 'potato' (you *know* someone will). Delegated to `get_float()`, where it belongs.
3. `if x == 0:` is unPythonic; PEP-8 says `if not x:` is preferred because it allows duck-typing - the function will now work on any type that knows how to do elementary operations. I don't know if it makes sense to apply Cramer's Law to tensors, but if it does, now you can.
4. Python operators obey order of operations; I got rid of a bunch of extraneous parentheses.

Hope that helps ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the try-except error handling pattern. Here's a basic example:

```
try:
    x = (((e * d) - (b * f)) / denominator)
except ZeroDivisionError:
   print("The equation has no solution.")
else:
   print("Success!")
```

Comment: I don't know about "should", but since this does show one approach of catching the exception ..

Answer (score 1):

Move your check for zero to earlier in your function like so:

```
...
denominator = ((a * d) - (b * c)

if denominator == 0:
    print("The equation has no solution.")
else:
    x = (((e * d) - (b * f)) / denominator)
    y = (((a * f) - (e * c)) / denominator)
    e = ((a * x) + (b * y)) 
    f = ((c * x) + (d * y))
    print("x is", x , "and y is" , y)
```